# Missing disk io schedulers

Tags: scheduler

The question is , where are the schedulers ?

```
# for f in /sys/block/sd?/queue/scheduler; do printf "$f is "; cat $f; done
/sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler is [mq-deadline] none
/sys/block/sdb/queue/scheduler is [mq-deadline] none
/sys/block/sdc/queue/scheduler is [mq-deadline] none
/sys/block/sdd/queue/scheduler is [mq-deadline] none

# uname -r
5.0.0-25-generic
```

i want to set cfq for my hdd disks not deadline

Answer (score 1):

Kernel 5 uses the following multiqueue I/O schedulers:

- bfq,
- kyber,
- mq-deadline

```
sudo modprobe bfq
cat /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler
[mq-deadline] bfq none
```

and enable it:

```
echo "bfq" | sudo tee /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler
```

This is where I got my information from:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Reference/IOSchedulers

Answer (score 1):

With Ubuntu Eoan 19.10 onwards, the legacy CFQ I/O scheduler is not available as this was deprecated in the kernel. Canonical kernel engineers won't support something that is not supported in the mainline 5.3 kernel.

You may find that bfq or kyber are worth trying instead. If you have a non-rotational drive (e.g. SSD), the current defaults should be perfect.  If you have rotational multi-queue drives, again the default may be fine without requiring a I/O scheduler change.